# authentication token verification for AJAX/xhr requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Seems that Rails has by default stopped checking authentication_token for ajax requests. per code request.xhr? is not checked anymore. It was not ignored in rails 2.3.2 but since 2.3.8 is ignored. Wanted to know what is the reason for this change and what uis the way to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

You need now check the format of the request to know what your want really served. It's really better than to know if you request is or not in xhr. This trick was bad because can be not support by all Javascript script.

Comment: Not sure what the format to serve has to do with checking for authentication_token to prevent CSRF. I would rather have the requests with invalid tokens be not served at all when using the security feature. Can you clarify.